# how can we run UI in background after its first time execution in java?

Tags: java, swing, singleton

The issue is when I am executing this application it always calls the UI of this application.
This is not what I want?
I want is it should execute/run UI only once after the first time and always run its backend.
And if I am closing or terminating the execution then and then It should run the UI again.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
     UI obj = new UI();  //Object of UI class that calls constructor and load UI(java swing)
     /*from the 1 st line below code is for back end that should be run every time but the first line 
     should be executed only once(this code is in main method and main method is called at every 15 
     minutes using jar file)*/
     String queryStringToCreateTable = null;
     Utils utility = new Utils();
     HTTPConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new HTTPConnectionManager();
     System.out.println("Processing started");
     String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
}
```

Comment: What is calling your `main` method and how is it done? Is there a new Process created each time or is the method simply called within your current runtime?

Comment: Is it a [singleton instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) of the `UI` that you are describing?

Comment: @Izuro- No, I have a jar file that executes our main method, this jar is placed in the windows scheduler. And it has functionality that the scheduler executes jar every 15 minutes.
So there is no new runtime or anything its just like jar is executed at every 15 minutes by the scheduler. The method is called within the current runtime.

Comment: @AndrewThompson- it is a singleton instance of UI.